# Displaying two components dynamically with React Typescrit

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In one page i wanna render two components at the same time. I have a bottom navbar that when i click on let's say profile icon, it will render the profile page. But i wanna change the color of the icon based in what component is being rendered. If i was using react router i could just check the current location, but in this case i'm in the same page and just changing one of the components, the only way i could think of changing the color dynamically is by getting the component's name. But i don't know how to do it with typescript.

I have this state:

```
const [page, setPage] = useState<React.ReactNode>(<UserChats />);
```

And i tried get the component's name by `page.type.name`, but it says that:

> Property 'type' does not exist on type 'string | number | boolean |
> ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor> | ReactFragment |
> ReactPortal'.

How can i get the component's name? Or, if there's a better way i'm all ears.

Comment: You shouldn't store React component inside state. Why don't you use a string to determine the color, for example?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try something like that?

```
const PAGE_STATE = {
    USER_CHAT: 'USER_CHAT',
    OTHER: 'OTHER'
};

const YourComponent = () => {
    const [pageState, setPageState] = useState(PAGE_STATE.USER_CHAT);

    return (
        <>
            {pageState === PAGE_STATE.USER_CHAT && <UserChat />}
            {pageState === PAGE_STATE.OTHER && <Other />
        </>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

// Store Components into enum
enum PageState {
  Chat = ChatPage,
  Other = OtherPage
}

const StatedPage = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState<PageState>(PageState.Chat); // can only set state as a member of PageState
  return (
    <>
      {state} // Render PageState's member value
    </>
  );
};

interface PageProps{
  state: PageState
}

const Page = (props: PageProps) => {
  return (
    <>
      {props.state}
    </>
  );
};

// Pass PageState member
<Page state={PageState.Chat} />
```

Comment: Plus use `react-router` if you want the "profile page" in separate page and still use the same layout